# Backtracking for permutations in c++

Tags: c++

I currently study permutations of a string where backtracking is used, and I am stuck at figuring out why does does this code goes back to i=0 when the function says it is on 1 for example, and so forth. But I do not understand a lot of this code so if anyone wants to help to explain this code to me I would be super thankful, thanks in advance!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// Function to find all Permutations of a given string str[i..n-1]
// containing all distinct characters
void permutations(string str, int i, int n)
{
    // base condition
    if (i == n - 1)
    {
        cout << str << endl;
        return;
    }

    // process each character of the remaining string
    for (int j = i; j < n; j++)
    {
        // swap character at index i with current character
        swap(str[i], str[j]);        // STL swap() used

        // recur for string [i+1, n-1]
        permutations(str, i + 1, n);

        // backtrack (restore the string to its original state)
        swap(str[i], str[j]);
    }
}

// Find all Permutations of a string
int main()
{
    string str = "ABC";

    permutations(str, 0, str.length());

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: To permute a string try each of the strings characters in the first position and permute the rest of the string. That's about it. In other words permute("ABC") = "A"+permute("BC") U "B"+ permute("AC") U "C"+permute("AB"). Somewhat dodgy notation, but hopefully you get the idea.

Comment: I understand that but how does this code do that?

Comment: It swaps each char into the first position and then calls itself recursively to permute the rest of the string.

Comment: But what does function do when we get to return, to which part of function does it go back?

Comment: It goes back to where it came from. Recursive functions are no different to ordinary functions. They return to the point just after where they were called. The call in main returns to main, the call in permuations returns to the code that swaps back the characters to how they were originally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll go through the steps it's taking to print all the permutations of the string "ABC".

1 - You call the function with `i = 0`.

2 - You enter the for loop and start with `j = i`.

3 - You swap `str[0]` with `str[0]`. (That does nothing).

4 - You recurse with `i = i + 1` (i = 1).

5 - You enter the loop again but this time `j = i = 1`.

6 - You swap `str[1]` with `str[1]` (That does nothing).

7 - You do recurse with `i = 2` and `str = "ABC"`. Since `i == n - 1` is true, this time you'll just print the result.

8 - You return from the call to the loop (with `i = 1`).

9 - You undo the swap that you've done before. Note that swapping the 2 elements twice is like doing nothing. In the first swap, the elements are swapped. In the second swap, the elements are back as they were before. In this case where `i = j`, You've swapped the same element with it self, so there is no effect form undoing what you did. But it'll be required when you swap 2 different characters.

10 - `j` gets incremented and becomes 2, and you swap `str[1]` with `str[2]`.

11 - You recurse again and call the function with `i = 2` and `str = "ACB"`. Again, this time you'll just print the result.

I think you can deduce what will happen next and how the rest of the strings are formed.

If you wanna follow the whole steps you can read this:

```
Entered the function with i = 0 and str = ABC
    Swapping str[0] (A) with str[0] (A)
    str = ABC
    Entered the function with i = 1 and str = ABC
        Swapping str[1] (B) with str[1] (B)
        str = ABC
        Entered the function with i = 2 and str = ABC
            Printing the string ABC
        Swapping str[1] (B) with str[1] (B) to restore the original state of the string
        str = ABC
        Swapping str[1] (B) with str[2] (C)
        str = ABC
        Entered the function with i = 2 and str = ACB
            Printing the string ACB
        Swapping str[1] (C) with str[2] (B) to restore the original state of the string
        str = ABC
    Exiting the function with i = 1 and str = ABC
    Swapping str[0] (A) with str[0] (A) to restore the original state of the string
    str = ABC
    Swapping str[0] (A) with str[1] (B)
    str = ABC
    Entered the function with i = 1 and str = BAC
        Swapping str[1] (A) with str[1] (A)
        str = BAC
        Entered the function with i = 2 and str = BAC
            Printing the string BAC
        Swapping str[1] (A) with str[1] (A) to restore the original state of the string
        str = BAC
        Swapping str[1] (A) with str[2] (C)
        str = BAC
        Entered the function with i = 2 and str = BCA
            Printing the string BCA
        Swapping str[1] (C) with str[2] (A) to restore the original state of the string
        str = BAC
    Exiting the function with i = 1 and str = BAC
    Swapping str[0] (B) with str[1] (A) to restore the original state of the string
    str = ABC
    Swapping str[0] (A) with str[2] (C)
    str = ABC
    Entered the function with i = 1 and str = CBA
        Swapping str[1] (B) with str[1] (B)
        str = CBA
        Entered the function with i = 2 and str = CBA
            Printing the string CBA
        Swapping str[1] (B) with str[1] (B) to restore the original state of the string
        str = CBA
        Swapping str[1] (B) with str[2] (A)
        str = CBA
        Entered the function with i = 2 and str = CAB
            Printing the string CAB
        Swapping str[1] (A) with str[2] (B) to restore the original state of the string
        str = CBA
    Exiting the function with i = 1 and str = CBA
    Swapping str[0] (C) with str[2] (A) to restore the original state of the string
    str = ABC
Exiting the function with i = 0 and str = ABC
```